# How to get xPath nodeValue USD dollar amount

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'm trying to start from the `<span>` element that has text **Value when transacted**

Then get its parent `<div>` and get following sibling which is a `<div>` and from that `<div>` get the text of the child `<span>`.

From what I can tell, the code is correct and should echo $1,034.29.

It echos $0.00 instead.

What am I missing here?

**php code:**

```
$a = new DOMXPath($doc);
$dep_val_txt = $a->query("//span[contains(text(), 'Value when transacted')]");
$dep_val_nxt_elem = $a->query("parent::div", $dep_val_txt[0]);
$dep_val_elem = $a->query("following-sibling::*[1]", $dep_val_nxt_elem[0]);
$dep_val = $dep_val_elem->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $dep_val;
```

**html code:**

```
<div class="sc-8sty72-0 cyLejs">
  <span class="sc-1ryi78w-0 bFGdFC sc-16b9dsl-1 iIOvXh sc-1n72lkw-0 bKaZjn" opacity="1">Value when transacted</span>
</div>
<div class="sc-8sty72-0 cyLejs">
  <span class="sc-1ryi78w-0 bFGdFC sc-16b9dsl-1 iIOvXh u3ufsr-0 gXDEBk" opacity="1">$1,034.29</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is it getting $0.00 from? Your code doesn't force it to format the output to look like currency, so I am wondering if the initial state of the page you are scraping actually has $0.00 in that element, and then a client side script updates the value in the DOM.

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez I was wondering the same.

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez yep that is what's going on. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No problem. What I would do here is examine where and how the client is fetching the data to replace the placeholders. If it’s making an API call, for example, simply use the same API to fetch the data you want.

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez ok yep I get it. I need to use an API call to get that value the same as the script in the page is getting it.

Comment: Bingo! That should do it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204155/discussion-between-michael-rodriguez-and-mike).

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else stumbles upon this question in the future, I will summarize the solution which was concluded by conversation with OP in the comments:

The issue here is not with the DOM selectors, as observed by the fact that his output is $0.00 even though he is not formatting the value to appear as a currency. This led me to believe that the website being scraped is in fact using placeholder values which are updated on the client side using Javascript. The reason this cannot be resolved with selectors is because the DOM received by PHP will be the initial render, which does not contain the values we wish to scrape.

So the solution is to examine the website being scraped to determine where and how the values are being fetched before being added to the DOM on the client side. For example, if the website is using an API call to fetch the values, one can simply use the same API to fetch the intended data without having to scrape the HTML DOM at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier and faster to process using a regex to match the price, here's a quick example in PHP:

```php
<?php

// Your input HTML (as per your example)
$inputHtml = <<<HTML
<div class="sc-8sty72-0 cyLejs">
  <span class="sc-1ryi78w-0 bFGdFC sc-16b9dsl-1 iIOvXh sc-1n72lkw-0 bKaZjn" opacity="1">Value when transacted</span>
</div>
<div class="sc-8sty72-0 cyLejs">
  <span class="sc-1ryi78w-0 bFGdFC sc-16b9dsl-1 iIOvXh u3ufsr-0 gXDEBk" opacity="1">$1,034.29</span>
</div>
HTML;

$matches = [];

// Look for any div > span element which contains a string starting with $ and then match a number (allowing for a , or . within the price matched).
if (preg_match_all('#<div.*>\s*<span.*?>\$([0-9.,]+)</span>\s*</div>#mis', $inputHtml, $matches)) {
    echo 'Price found: ' . $matches[1][0] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Console output from this:

```
Price found: 1,034.29
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but still if the initial render of the website OP is scraping has $0.00, and relies on a client side script for updating the DOM with actual data, then this still won't work. What I mean is, this will still return $0.00.

Comment: If they're using React or something similar to update the DOM with the price onDocumentReady or similar, then there's not much you can do from a pure PHP perspective, unless you were to fetch the DOM in a browser, then pass the rendered HTML back to a script to handle after it's updated.

Comment: @Aran it is updated somehow after page loads. Can you give me an example of fetch the DOM then pass rendered HTML to script?

Comment: @Aran correct that’s the point I wanted to make :) your answer is good, but it doesn’t solve OP’s issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't be able to get the rendered HTML using PHP alone, you might want to take a look at something like PhantomJS.

If you needed to, you could call it (`exec(...)`) from PHP, and then get the output back and parse as above in your PHP logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow OPs question literally

```
start from the <span> element that has text "Value when transacted"
get its parent <div>
get following sibling which is a <div> 
get the text of the child <span>
```

then the xpath expression should be

```
//span[text()='Value when transacted']/parent::div/following-sibling::div/span
```

Comment: Yes but read the comments. The page he is scraping has placeholder values, so the DOM received by PHP doesn’t contain the data OP wants to scrape. His selectors would otherwise work, even if they are not optimal, it’s just that the actual data is not yet present.

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez - Yes, I did read the comments and that part is over my pay grade... I was just trying to create an xpath expression which follows OPs road map to the letter, in case that helps.

Comment: @JackFleeting thanks for shortening and optimizing the query though.